# Lower casing solves an ElasticSearch term query but I do not understand why

Tags: elasticsearch

I have successfully indexed a document with the field `docket.id` set to `p_CentralGrocers`. However then when I try to query all documents with the field `docket.id: p_CentralGrocers` I get zero results. If I lowercase the `docket.id` then suddenly everything works fine. While I could as a hack just lower case my queries, the ID's may no longer be unique creating problems for my database down the road. The response from my `explain` query is quite unhelpful (see below, somehow this document's `docket.id` got changed to 0), it doesn't answer at all why the MixedCase query failed while the lowercase query succeeds fine. Let me know if there is something I'm doing wrong on the index mapping or elsewhere.

```
GET bankrupt_documents/_doc/p_CentralGrocers3349
{
  "_index" : "bankrupt_documents",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "p_CentralGrocers3349",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_seq_no" : 0,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "docket" : {
      "id" : "p_CentralGrocers",
      "name" : "Central Grocers, Inc."
    },
    "content" ...
```

```
GET bankrupt_documents/_explain/p_CentralGrocers3349
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "docket.id": "p_CentralGrocers"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
***RESPONSE***
{
  "_index" : "bankrupt_documents",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "p_CentralGrocers3349",
  "matched" : false,
  "explanation" : {
    "value" : 0.0,
    "description" : "ConstantScore(docket.id:p_CentralGrocers) doesn't match id 0",
    "details" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use _analyze endpoint to see what kind of tokens are generated. Here we are analyzing text "p_CentralGrocers3349" with standard analyzer which is default analyzer for fields of type text.

```
GET index74/_analyze
{
  "text": ["p_CentralGrocers3349"],
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

**Result:**

```
 "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "p_centralgrocers3349",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 20,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
```

If you will see by default tokens are lower cased, this helps to do case insensitive match. Tokens are also split on whitespace and special characters by standard analyzer

```
GET index74/_analyze
{
  "text": ["p_CentralGrocers3349 abc"],
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

Result:

```
 "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "p_centralgrocers3349",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 20,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "abc",
      "start_offset" : 21,
      "end_offset" : 24,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
```

Splitting of tokens make text field unsuitable for term query whose purpose is to do exact match. If you want to do exact match , use term query on keyword field. By default each text field is created with a keyword field field. If you are explicitly creating mapping you can define one like below

```
PUT index74
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id":{
        "type":"text",
        "fields":{
          "keyword":{
            "type":"keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "id.keyword": {
        "value": "p_CentralGrocers3349"
      }
    }
  }
}
```